# Ionic 4 side menu routing doesn't load on its own page

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I add a new menu on my sidemenu in project. I connect it with a service. But when i click menu it doesn't load page. and it doesn't give me an error. I can't understand why it is happen.

If you want, i can write here service and page modules.

I add some codes of my project. Please help me.

My app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  public appPages = [
    {
      title: 'Home',
      url: '/home',
      icon: 'home'
    },
    {
      title: 'List',
      url: '/list',
      icon: 'list'
    },
    {
      title: 'Users',
      url: '/user',
      icon: 'person'
    }

  ];
constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
```

My app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'list',
    loadChildren: './list/list.module#ListPageModule'
  },
  { path: 'detail/:id', loadChildren: './detail/detail.module#DetailPageModule' },
  { path: 'user', loadChildren: './user/user.module#UserPageModule' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

My app-.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { PostService } from './services/post.service';

import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide:"apiUrl",useValue:"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/"},
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    PostService,
    HttpClient
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

My Side Menu Code:

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-split-pane>
    <ion-menu>
      <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar>
          <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>
      <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
          <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of appPages">
            <ion-item [routerDirection]="'root'" [routerLink]="[p.url]">
              <ion-icon slot="start" [name]="p.icon"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label>
                {{p.title}}
              </ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-menu-toggle>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-menu>
    <ion-router-outlet main></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-split-pane>
</ion-app>
```

Comment: can you show your sidemenu html code. As well as which page isn't loading ?

Comment: I wrote my html code above question. The unworking link is 'user'

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
<ion-item [routerDirection]="'root'" [routerLink]="[p.url]">
```

and click on it the url will be passed as a parameter like :/home

In your case since you are taking it from a list

```
<ion-item [routerDirection]="'root'" routerLink="{{p.url}}">
```

or

```
<ion-item [routerDirection]="'root'" [routerLink]="p.url">
```

Comment: Sorry forgot that it came from a ngFor making the require edits

Comment: I undo my change

Comment: The error is my html code. I edit it and the list is good for now. Thanks for your time